# What is the complexity of finding of all paths

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, pseudocode

There is a map, consisting of hexagonal fields. On this map we have a pawn. He cannot visit any location twice. What is the complexity of an algorithm that's going to find ALL possible paths without repetitions? (basically finding all possible paths, not necessary going through all fields, as it's possible the pawn will run himself into a corner, he goes as long as ha can move).

Comment: Complexity depends on the shape of the map.

Comment: @Oswald well, I guess hexagon shaped map is the worst case scenario? In such situation would it be n (where n is number of fields) or n^2? or n! ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity is O(5<sup>n</sup>).

- From every field except the first one, at most 5 moves are possible.
- If the pawn is moved to a field, it creates a unique path (no checking necessary, whether the path is already visited).
- Keeping track of which fields can be visited from any given field can be done in O(1).

Lower bounds might exist depending on the shape of the map.

Comment: Actually, wouldn't it be 5^n ? After all, only the first move gives us 6 possible paths, every next move is going to have one path already taken (the one used to get to it)

Answer (score 1):

First the bounds of answer for **given** map of n fields and **given** start position (i.e. for algorithm designed specially for the configuration and starting position): from O(n) (O(1) if there can be isolated hexes) to O(e^n).

I mean, if map is line of hexes, there is only 1 path if starting position is at the end of the line and 2 paths otherwise, no matter what is value of n. If map is a circle of hexes, there is always 1 path. On the other hand, if significant parts of the map are "squares" of connected hexes, number of paths grows exponentially, and algorithm finding all paths can't go any faster than that (even if paths are somehow obvious, we still have to output them).

**If** configuration of the map and starting position are also inputs of algorithm, question becomes more difficult: in theory, algorithm can try to 'analyze' map first to see if it is 'specific' enough (for example, map can have repeating pattern that can be analyzed only once) and go on such map better than Oswald's algorithm.

For 'average' map consisting of **connected** hexes, number of paths seems to be exponential (I don't have a strict proof for that), so algorithm complexity by time is also exponential (can't go better and Oswald's algorithm reaches that limit). Exact value of exponent for average random map paths will be *hard* to evaluate and probably isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, on a random map, the complexity of this algorithm will be `O(x)` where `x` is the answer for this map.

Comment: Where x is number of fields?

Comment: @Xyzk no. I'll try to explain. On a random map, we cannot (or I don't see how) count the number of such paths without actually finding all these paths. And finding all there paths mean that the complexity is at least O(x), where x is their number. And this could actually be done in O(x) time using DFS.

Comment: I didn't know we can exploit big-Oh notation like this. "`O(x)` where `x` is the answer"

Comment: Did you mean Omega(x) as a lower bound, rather than O(x) as an upper bound?

Comment: @justhalf- It's indeed possible to do this. You might want to look up the term "output-sensitive algorithm."